# Wrong placement of figure caption in floatcombination

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, context

This is my code:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\starttext
  \tikzset{
    cflow/.style={draw=black, ellipse, text centered, minimum width=1cm},
    arr/.style = {->,>=stealth},
  }
  \startfloatcombination[distance=10pt]
    \startplacetable[force,title={My Table}]
      \starttable[|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l]
        \NC P \VL f1 \NC f2 \NC f3 \NC f4 \NC f5 \NC f6 \NC f7 \NC f8 \NC f9 \AR
        \HL \NC A \VL c \NC b \NC c \NC - \NC - \NC - \NC - \NC a \NC - \AR
      \stoptable
    \stopplacetable
    \startplacefigure[force,title={My Graph}]
      \starttikzpicture
        \node[cflow] (f1) {f1};
        \node[cflow,right=of f1] (f8) {f8};
        \node[cflow,right=of f8] (f2) {f2};
        \node[cflow,below=of f1] (f4) {f4};
        \node[cflow,below=of f8] (f6) {f6};
        \node[cflow,below=of f2] (f5) {f5};
        \node[cflow,below=of f4] (f9) {f9};
        \node[cflow,below=of f6] (f7) {f7};
        \node[cflow,below=of f5] (f3) {f3};

        \draw[arr] (f1) -- (f4);
        \draw[arr] (f1) -- (f6);
        \draw[arr] (f2) -- (f5);
        \draw[arr] (f3) -- (f7);
        \draw[arr] (f4) -- (f9);
        \draw[arr] (f6) to[bend left] (f7);
        \draw[arr] (f7) to[bend left] (f6);
        \draw[arr] (f8) -- (f2);
      \stoptikzpicture
    \stopplacefigure
  \stopfloatcombination
\stoptext
```

It yields:

[image]

Why is the second caption misplaced? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is an old "bug" that I had reported to the pgf mailing list in Oct 2009: see [this thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2009/042580.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so sure what is going on under the hood, but you have to wrap the `tikzpicture` inside a `framed`.  Actually, `\hbox` suffices, but `framed` is semantically nicer.  I guess it has to do with the fact that TeX is in vmode at that point and simply wraps the `tikzpicture` into a vbox of width `\textwidth`.

Furthermore, the syntax for `force` is wrong, it has to be `location={force}`.  However, in this setting it has no effect and I removed it.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\starttext
  \tikzset{
    cflow/.style={draw=black, ellipse, text centered, minimum width=1cm},
    arr/.style = {->,>=stealth},
  }
  \startfloatcombination[distance=10pt]
    \startplacetable[title={My Table}]
      \starttable[|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l]
        \NC P \VL f1 \NC f2 \NC f3 \NC f4 \NC f5 \NC f6 \NC f7 \NC f8 \NC f9 \AR
        \HL \NC A \VL c \NC b \NC c \NC - \NC - \NC - \NC - \NC a \NC - \AR
      \stoptable
    \stopplacetable
    \startplacefigure[title={My Graph}]
      \startframed[frame=off,offset=none]
        \starttikzpicture
          \node[cflow] (f1) {f1};
          \node[cflow,right=of f1] (f8) {f8};
          \node[cflow,right=of f8] (f2) {f2};
          \node[cflow,below=of f1] (f4) {f4};
          \node[cflow,below=of f8] (f6) {f6};
          \node[cflow,below=of f2] (f5) {f5};
          \node[cflow,below=of f4] (f9) {f9};
          \node[cflow,below=of f6] (f7) {f7};
          \node[cflow,below=of f5] (f3) {f3};

          \draw[arr] (f1) -- (f4);
          \draw[arr] (f1) -- (f6);
          \draw[arr] (f2) -- (f5);
          \draw[arr] (f3) -- (f7);
          \draw[arr] (f4) -- (f9);
          \draw[arr] (f6) to[bend left] (f7);
          \draw[arr] (f7) to[bend left] (f6);
          \draw[arr] (f8) -- (f2);
        \stoptikzpicture
      \stopframed
    \stopplacefigure
  \stopfloatcombination
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

If you don’t want to take care to wrap the `tikzpicture` into `framed` everytime you are in vmode, you can also adjust the definition of `\start...\stoptikzpicture`.

```
\unprotect

\let\old_start_tikz_picture=\starttikzpicture
\let\old_stop_tikz_picture =\stoptikzpicture

\newconditional\tikz_picture_started_in_vmode

\starttexdefinition unexpanded starttikzpicture
  \setfalse\tikz_picture_started_in_vmode
  \ifvmode
    \startframed[frame=off,offset=none]
    \settrue\tikz_picture_started_in_vmode
  \fi
  \old_start_tikz_picture
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition unexpanded stoptikzpicture
  \old_stop_tikz_picture
  \ifconditional\tikz_picture_started_in_vmode
    \stopframed
  \fi
\stoptexdefinition

\protect
```

Comment: A `\dontleavehmode` should also suffice

Comment: @Aditya Unfortunately no.  This was the first thing I tried as I was thinking that the `tikzpicture` does not interrupt vmode but it is not the case.  Only `\hbox{...}` (or other boxes) work.